# Count the number of whitespaces in a file

Tags: bash, macos, grep

File `test`

```
musically us
challenged a goat that day
spartacus was his name
ba ba ba blacksheep
```

- `grep -oic "[\s]*" test`
- `grep -oic "[ ]*" test`
- `grep -oic "[\t]*" test`
- `grep -oic "[\n]*" test`

All give me 4, when I expect 11

`grep --version` -> `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`

Running this on OSX Sierra 10.12

Repeating spaces should not be counted as one space.

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to tricks and alternatives you might like this one:

```
$ awk '{print --NF}' <(tr -d '\n' <file)
11
```

Above solution will count "whitespace" between words. As a result for a string of `'fifteen-->               <--spaces'` awk will measure 1, like grep.

If you need to count actual single spaces you can use this :

```
$ awk -F"[ ]" '{print --NF}' <<<"fifteen-->               <--spaces"
15
$ awk -F"[ ]" '{print --NF}' <<<"  2  4  6  8  10"
10
$ awk -F"[ ]" '{print --NF}' <(tr -d '\n' <file)
11
```

One step forward, to count single spaces and tabs:

```
$ awk -F"[ ]|\t" '{print --NF}' <(echo -e "  2  4  6  8  10\t12  14")
13
```

Comment: Why the need for awk here? It just breaks the capability of `tr`.

Comment: @l'L'l  In this example , awk does the counting instead of wc

Comment: But the count then becomes inaccurate; try for example `"  2  4  6  8  10"` and see what the count is... *two spaces between numbers

Comment: This solution would work if we were to count both spaces and tabs.   Can the `tr` solution do that as well?

Comment: PS: This is the magic about SO. I would have not thought alone to test my initial proposal to a string like `"fifteen-->               <--spaces"`. But thanks to other users i can improve my code to be better. Though still code might not be perfect.

Comment: @codeforester: If you mean multiple criteria at the same time (counting tabs and spaces) then `tr` would need two instances, whereas I'm assuming  by what you say this one only might need a regex `|`... which would make this one the better solution; it was quickly fixed to become a winner...

Comment: `tr -dC $'[ \t]'  <<< $'one \t' | wc -c` does show 2.  So, `tr` can handle both tabs and spaces as well.  I voted up both the answers.  I liked your `tr` idea very much.

Comment: @codeforester: Thanks, I didn't even think about doing it that way, so that's quite cool actually :)

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks for the correction. Upvoted your answer also.

Comment: I think the moral of the story here is use `tr`! :) The `grep` answer chosen as "correct" is not so good.

Answer (score 2):

`tr` is generally better for this (in most cases):

```
tr -d -C ' ' <file | wc -c
```

The `grep` solution relies on the fact that the output of `grep -o` is newline-separated — it will fail miserably for example in the following type of circumstance where there might be multiple spaces:

```
v='fifteen-->               <--spaces'

echo "$v" | grep -o -E ' +' | wc -l

echo "$v" | tr -d -C ' ' | wc -c
```

`grep` only returns 1, when it should be **15**.

**EDIT**: If you wanted to count multiple characters (eg. <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>SPACE</kbd>) you could use:

```
tr -dC $'[ \t]' <<< $'one \t' | wc -c
```

Comment: Just for completeness i would propose to include codeforester's great suggestion about handling both tab and spaces using `$'[ \t]'` that appears as comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` option counts the number of lines that match, not individual matches. Use `grep -o` and then pipe to `wc -l`, which will count the number of lines.

```
grep -o ' ' test | wc -l
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer because it gives wrong result when there are repeated whitespaces on the same line.  These answers below are better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43421221/6862601 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/43421116/6862601

Comment: @codeforester All his original attempts use `*` to combine repeated whitespaces together, so I assumed he wanted to count them once.

Comment: @Barmar actually, I am a woman. Also, fixed my original post to clarify my ask.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's hard to tell on the Internet. I changed my answer to get rid of the `+` quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' 'END{print NR-1}' file
11
```

or if you want to handle empty files gracefully:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' 'END{print NR - (NR?1:0)}' /dev/null
0
```